# Getting "object of type 'NoneType' has no len()" during implementation of mergeSort

Tags: python, python-3.x, mergesort

I'm trying to implement mergeSort in python but getting Type error.

I tried debugging my code but didn't got any success.

```
def merge(L, R):
    (C, m, n) = ([], len(L), len(R))
    (i,j) = (0,0)

    while i+j < m+n:
        if i == m: # Case 1 -> List A is empty
            C.append(R[j])
            j += 1
        elif j == n: # Case 2 -> List B is empty
            C.append(L[i])
            i += 1
        elif L[i] <= R[j]: # Case 3 -> Head of A is smaller 
            C.append(L[i])
            i += 1
        elif L[i] > R[j]:
            C.append(R[j])
            j += 1
    print(C)

def mergeSort(A, left, right):

    if right - left <= 1: # Base Case
        return(A[left:right])
    if right - left > 1: # Recurive call
        mid = (left+right)//2

        L = mergeSort(A, left, mid)
        R = mergeSort(A, mid, right)

        return(merge(L, R))
```

If anyone know what I'm doing wrong, please guide me to the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`merge` has to return `C`, not print it.

```
def merge(L, R):
    (C, m, n) = ([], len(L), len(R))
    (i,j) = (0,0)

    while i+j < m+n:
        if i == m: # Case 1 -> List A is empty
            C.append(R[j])
            j += 1
        elif j == n: # Case 2 -> List B is empty
            C.append(L[i])
            i += 1
        elif L[i] <= R[j]: # Case 3 -> Head of A is smaller 
            C.append(L[i])
            i += 1
        elif L[i] > R[j]:
            C.append(R[j])
            j += 1
    return C
```

Comment: The return value of `mergeSort` is the return value of `merge`, and the return value of `mergeSort` is what gets passed as the arguments to `merge`.

Comment: @sumit4613 - or you could pass A as an argument to merge, to avoid having to make uneeded copies.

Comment: @rcgldr merge here isn't sorting the list, it only merge two sorted lists. Is there any more efficient way to implement this I would like to know as I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any more efficient way to implement this

Top down merge sort using a pair of mutually recursive functions (msa2a, msa2b) to change the direction of merge and avoid copying of data:

```
def sort(a):
    if(len(a) < 2):                     # if nothing to do, return
        return
    b = [0] * len(a)                    # allocate b
    msa2a(a, b, 0, len(a))              # merge sort a to a

def msa2a(a, b, low, end):              # merge sort a to a
    if((end - low) < 2):                # if < 2 elements
        return                          #   return
    mid = (low+end)//2                  # set mid point
    msa2b(a, b, low, mid)               # merge sort left  half to b
    msa2b(a, b, mid, end)               # merge sort right half to b
    mrg(b, a, low, mid, end)            # merge halves   from b to a

def msa2b(a, b, low, end):              # merge sort a to b
    if((end - low) < 2):                # if < 2 elements
        b[low] = a[low]                 #   copy 1 element from a to b
        return                          #   return
    mid = (low+end)//2                  # set mid point
    msa2a(a, b, low, mid)               # merge sort left  half to a
    msa2a(a, b, mid, end)               # merge sort right half to a
    mrg(a, b, low, mid, end)            # merge halves   from a to b

def mrg(a, b, ll, rr, ee):              # merge a pair of runs from a to b
    o = ll                              # o = b[]        index
    l = ll                              # l = a[] left   index
    r = rr                              # r = a[] right  index
    while True:
        if(a[l] <= a[r]):               # if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o] = a[l]                 #   copy a[l]
            o += 1
            l += 1
            if(l < rr):                 #   if not end of left run
                continue                #     continue (back to while)
            b[o:ee] = a[r:ee]           #   else copy rest of right run
            return                      #     and return
        else:                           # else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o] = a[r]                 #   copy a[r]
            o += 1
            r += 1
            if(r < ee):                 #   if not end of right run
                continue                #     continue (back to while)
            b[o:ee] = a[l:rr]           #   else copy rest of left run
            return                      #     and return
```

Bottom up merge sort is only slightly faster, but for this version if the number of passes would be odd, it swaps in place for the first pass, which helps further still. The merge function (mrg) is identical to the top down merge sort shown above.

```
def sort(a):
    if(len(a) < 2):                     # if nothing to do, return
        return
    b = [0] * len(a)                    # allocate b
    mrgsrt(a, b, len(a))

def mrgsrt(a, b, n):
    s = 1                               # assume even pass count
    if((passcnt(n) & 1) == 1):          #  if odd count
        while(s < n):                   #   swap pairs in place
            if(a[s] < a[s-1]):
                a[s-1],a[s] = a[s],a[s-1]
            s = s + 2
        s = 2
    while(s < n):
        ee = 0                          # reset end index
        while(ee < n):                  # setup for next pair of runs
            ll = ee
            rr = ll + s
            if(rr >= n):                #  if only left run copy it
                b[ll:n] = a[ll:n]
                break
            ee = rr + s
            if(ee > n):
                ee = n
            mrg(a, b, ll, rr, ee)
        a,b = b,a                       # swap(a, b)
        s = s << 1                      # double run size

def mrg(a, b, ll, rr, ee):              # merge a pair of runs from a to b
    o = ll                              # o = b[]        index
    l = ll                              # l = a[] left   index
    r = rr                              # r = a[] right  index
    while True:
        if(a[l] <= a[r]):               # if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o] = a[l]                 #   copy a[l]
            o += 1
            l += 1
            if(l < rr):                 #   if not end of left run
                continue                #     continue (back to while)
            b[o:ee] = a[r:ee]           #   else copy rest of right run
            return                      #     and return
        else:                           # else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o] = a[r]                 #   copy a[r]
            o += 1
            r += 1
            if(r < ee):                 #   if not end of right run
                continue                #     continue (back to while)
            b[o:ee] = a[l:rr]           #   else copy rest of left run
            return                      #     and return

def passcnt(n):                         # return # passes
    i = 0
    s = 1
    while(s < n):
        s = s << 1
        i = i + 1
    return(i)
```

Faster still would be a hybrid insertion + merge sort, using insertion sort for runs <= 64 elements (depends on element size). I don't have python code for an example of this. Since python is interpretive, it's slower, in the example merge sorts shown above, python takes about 64 times as long as essentially the same code compiled in C++.